# How to get text between delimiters in specific positions/indices in a concise way (e.g regular expression)?

Tags: java, regex

I have strings with specific delimiters like

`String str = "some other text @ test text between @ another text @ extra text";`

What I am trying to do is given two indices I want to get the in between text of those delimiters without the delimiters..

So for:

```
 ("@", 0,1) => "test text between"
 ("@", 1,2) => "another text"
 ("@", 0,2) => "test text between another text"
```

I know how to do it using a StringTokenizer/split. Something along those lines:

```
        public static String getTextBetweenDelimiterPositions(String str, String delimiter, int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
            if (fromIndex >= toIndex) return null;

            StringTokenizer strTok = new StringTokenizer(str, delimiter, true);
            int tokenIndex = 0;
            StringBuilder keep = new StringBuilder();
            while(strTok.hasMoreTokens()) {
                String token = strTok.nextToken();

                if (!token.equals(delimiter) && tokenIndex > fromIndex && tokenIndex <=toIndex) {
                    keep.append(token.trim()+" ");
                }
                if (token.equals(delimiter)){
                    tokenIndex++;
                }
            }
            return keep.toString().trim();
        }
```

I wonder if it is possible to do it with regular expressions for example.

Comment: You could split your string on `@` then join wanted elements.

Comment: "test text between another text" is not a string that appears in the original text, so it's impossible for that to be the match of a regexp group. At minimum you'd need to follow up with a replace. However there are many possible ways to go about it.

Comment: @Toto yeah I know I can do it with split/StringTokenizer

Comment: @PatrickParker I see .. I thought It is possible to do a "not in set of chars" ```^[@]``` somehow but using regular expression backtracking and indices that I am not familiar with..

Answer (score 1):

Not in Java (in Perl with a Bash wrapper), but may be useful to demonstrate the general regex idea:

```
#!/bin/bash
s=" @ " # delimiter
for a in $(seq 0 3); do 
  for b in $(seq $a 3); do 
    echo "$a $b"
    echo "aaa @ bbb @ ccc @ ddd @ eee" | perl -nle "
      if (m/(?:.*?$s){$a}((?:.*?$s){$[b-a]})/) { # if matches
        # do some post-processing (replace " @ " with "" etc.)
        print '[', \$1 =~ s/$s/ /gr =~ s/ \$//r, ']'
      }
    "
  done
done
```

Output:

```
0 2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
[aaa bbb]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
0 3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
[aaa bbb ccc]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
1 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
[]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
1 2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
[bbb]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
1 3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
[bbb ccc]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
2 2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
[]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
2 3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
[ccc]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
3 3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
[]
```